# How to import EF 3.0 method in Brightway2?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, brightway

My colleague, after the recent update of Brightway2, can see EF3.0 method within the availeable.
I tried to do the same but it's not working (I have some new methods, but not EF3.0).
This is what I have done:

```
Conda update conda
Conda update brightway2
```

In Brightway

```
import brightway2 as bw
```

```
bw.Database('biosphere3').delete()
bw.Database('biosphere3').deregister()
```

```
bw.projects
bw.projects.delete_project('Name of my project',delete_dir=True)
bw.projects.report()
```

```
bw.databases
bw.databases.clear()
```

```
bw.bw2setup() #Import of biosphere3
```

```
# Import ecoinvent 3.7 

ei37dir ="*my directory*"

if 'ecoinvent 3.7_cutoff' in bw.databases:
    print("Database has already been imported")
else:
    ei37 = bw.SingleOutputEcospold2Importer(ei37dir, 'ecoinvent 3.7_cutoff') 
    ei37.apply_strategies()
    ei37.statistics()
    ei37.drop_unlinked(True)

ei37.write_database()
```

```
list(bw.methods)
```

How can I implement EF3.0?
Thank you in advance

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EF method was added in `bw2io` version 0.8.6. You would need to update to this library version, and then reinstall the LCIA methods (doesn't have anything to do with which version of ecoinvent you have, LCIA methods are separate).

In a new project, just calling `bw2setup()` should be fine. In an older project, you will need to rewrite both biosphere flow list and the LCIA methods:

```py
import bw2io as bi
bi.create_default_biosphere3(overwrite=True)
bi.create_default_lcia_methods(overwrite=True)
```